# What are the regularity conditions of the Bernstein-von Mises theorem in simple one-dimensional case?

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, bayesian

I would like to apply the Bernstein-von Mises theorem in a very simple settings to be able to make the following claim:

> Let $\theta \in [0,1]$ be a random parameter with strictly positive and bounded probability density function. Its observations $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are i.i.d. normally distributed, specifically $X_n \sim N(\theta, 1)$. Then $\sqrt{n}(\theta-\theta_0)$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$.

What are the regularity conditions that need to be satisfied? [Wikipedia page on the Bernstein-von Mises theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%E2%80%93von_Mises_theorem) only states *"finite-dimensional, well-specified, smooth, existence of tests"*. However, I would need a precise formulation of the assumption for this simple one-dimensional setting. What would be a good reference book with a simple formulation of the theorem? I found only the book *Asymptotic Statistics* by A. W. van der Vaart, which however treats unnecessarily general case.

Comment: You can refer to [*An Introduction to Bayesian Analysis*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-35433-0) by Ghosh et al.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks a lot for the reference. This presentation (Theorem 4.2) is much easier for me to understand and apply than the one predented in the A. W. van der Vaart's book. I suppose that the assumptions A1-A4 are satisfied trivially in case of normally distributed observation error, yet it is not something straight forward (to verify them means a page of redundant technical text), it would be great to have a theorem or corollary that states the version of the theorem applied to observations with normally distributed error.

Comment: I also wish that the limit was about the tern $t=\sqrt{n}(\theta - \theta_0)$ (given $X_1,\ldots,X_n$) instead of $t=\sqrt{n}(\theta - \hat\theta_n)$ as it is in Theorem 4.2 in the Ghosh et al.'s book.